# Clothes shrinking inside my character

Tags: mesh, physics

I've been doing a character for the last days and I'm currently trying to make some clothes, I had some prototypes done and after finishing some corrections to my characters mesh I applied the subdivision modifier, right after that all the clothes start shrinking inside my character

Comment: Can you please add images? It's extremely difficult to say anything without them.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it accidentally, I think what happened was a wrong orientation of the faces and it was fixed when I recalculate them for the mesh painting, thanks anyways